# How to share a workbook with client in Tableau who do not have Tableau account or tableau reader

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

I want to share my workbook with client who do not have tableau account and tableau reader.
I want to share a URL which they can access without doing any login.
user should not be able to download or see the data.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There may not be a solution to this without paying for a subscription.

You can share using Tableau Public - but anyone is able to see that. You can prevent download in Tableau Public, so if it's ok to share the aggregate numbers displayed in your dashboard this could work.

With Tableau Reader, you're also sending all of the data, so rule it out based on your requirements.

Other options mean paying - either Tableau Online or Tableau Server.